# How to Run incremental Code scan in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sonarlint

I am using visual Studio 2017 and sonarlist extension for code scan. Language is C#.I understand by default visual Studio does live scan for open documents.
Is there any way I can scan only the changed/modified files in current changeset? Not necessarily I should open all documents and also I don't want full solution scan.
This way I can ensure new changesets are being pushed with good quality.

Please suggest.

Comment: You could select to display "Only modified documents" in the error list, although I don't know whether this has actually an effect on the scan itself. To my knowledge it can't be configured that granular.

Comment: We need to detect code smell introduced by newly added code and not analysis report for each worked file. For example one file might have 50 legacy issues but if my newly added code fixes 10 issues but in turn introduces 5 new issues then I need to see those 5 issues locally in visual studio.

This is the same way teamcity is giving us scan report after build. Please suggest how can I detect new leak using sonarlint and visual studio